# Firebase push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Push Notification for iOS using Firebase. I have followed all the steps mentioned over there for push notifications.

When I try to send a message from Firebase server to my app, I get the error in server saying `Unregistered registration token`.

I am using the token generated in the app. Using this code to get the token :

```
[FIRApp configure];
NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
```

Comment: what about the web api and api in the google-info plist should they be matching.

Answer (score 0):

The `Not Registered` happens when `GCM` thinks the device could not handle the message. This happens if the app is uninstalled or misconfigured to handle the message, try uninstalling app manually from phone and run it again

Comment: tried it, message delivers for first time after that it fails with same error.

Answer (score -1):

In my app this line was in an If condition, so not called it always.
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];`